# How do I add spell-checking dictionaries without adding a keyboard layout in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-pack

I have 2 custom keyboard layouts that I've created using MSKLC. Now I want to add just spell-checking dictionaries. But when I add a new language, it adds another layout that I can't remove (the button is disabled). Is it even possible?

Comment: Is the spell-check in a specific application? For example, Notepad++, Firefox and LibreOffice use separate spellcheck dictionaries, see https://www.guidingtech.com/1994/edit-firefox-dictionary-spell-check/ for Firefox's.

Comment: This is for Telegram, it uses OS's spell-check.